# How to get a column from selected row from jqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid, asp-classic

I am using JQGrid in my asp. And i enabled the feature `multiselect:true`.
How to get a column from selected row from jqGrid?
Now I am getting the row index using

`var rowRule = jQuery("#list").getGridParam('selarrrow');`

Using this index of row how can i get the first column of row is there any predefined method for this? If exist please let me know.

I tried this:

```
var grid = jQuery("#<%= JQGrid1.ClientID %>");  
var rowKey = grid.getGridParam("selrow");
```

This is not working in classic asp

Thanks in advance.
Vissu.P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery("#list").getGridParam('selarrrow')` returns the list of rowids of selected rows. You can use `getCell` method in the loop to get the contain of the column which you need from every selected row and place the contain in an array:

```
var selIds = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow'),
    selText = [];
$.each(selIds,function() {
    selText.push(grid.jqGrid('getCell',this,'name'));
});
```

See the demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithMultiselect.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem should not have anything to do with your server-side platform (Classic ASP, ASP.NET, etc), since you are using JavaScript to get the ID of the selected row. Try this instead to get the selected Row ID:

```
var grid = jQuery("#<%= JQGrid1.ClientID %>");
var rowKey = grid.jqGrid('GetGridParam', 'selrow');
```